# Incorporating value from $http.get and $scope into 2 way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have user input change a value on the scope using 2 way data binding. I think because the value is calculated inside of an $http success function it doesn't allow two way data binding to take place. Does anybody know of a good solution to allow the $scope.btc amount to update dynamically based on the $scope.usd input?

controller:

```
    $scope.usd = 0;

    $http({
        method:'GET' , 
        url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinbase.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fcurrencies%2Fexchange_rates'
    }).
    success(function(data,status,headers,config){

        $scope.btc = parseFloat(data.btc_to_usd) * $scope.usd
    }).
    error(function(data,status,headers,config){

        console.log('failure')
    });
```

view:

```
h1(class='pageTitle') Bitcoin Invoice
        label Amount USD:    
            input(type='text' ng-model='usd' style='margin-left:30px')
           br
         label Amount BTC:           
            input(type='text' ng-model='btc' style='margin-left:39px')
          br
          label Description:   
        input(type='text' ng-model='description' style='margin-left:3px')
```

Comment: The problem is not with the remote call. Put breakpoint on line `$scope.btc = parseFloat(data.btc_to_usd) * $scope.usd` and see if it is being hit and what the value of btc is.

Answer (score 0):

please see here: http://jsbin.com/dajus/1/ just change a bit your $http call

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.usd = 10;


  $http.get('https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcoinbase.com%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fcurrencies%2Fexchange_rates').
    then(function(response,status,headers,config){        


        $scope.btc = parseFloat(response.data.btc_to_usd) * $scope.usd;
    },
    function(data,status,headers,config){

        console.log('failure');
    });

});
```

Comment: I'm trying to dynamically update the input fields. So if the user inputs 10 in the USD input it will render 10 x btc_to_usd exchange rate.